# Show retweeters of a Twitter status in Tweepy

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

I've been trying to find a way of doing the equivalent of:

```
retweeters_of('twitterstatusid')
```

I can't see an explicit method in `tweepy` - and couldn't work out any other way of finding this. Any help appreciated.

Comment: What language/platform is this? Please tag accordingly.

Comment: Python - have added tag.

Comment: Solved:

    results = api.retweeted_by('statusid')

Method was missing form documentation.

Comment: Post your solution as an answer.

Comment: You can find the updated solution [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17725145/4572985).

Answer (score 3):

Solved:

```
results = api.retweeted_by('statusid')
```

(This method was missing from documentation.)