# Retweeters of a Twitter status in Tweepy

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

This is kindof a followup question to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5688762/show-retweeters-of-a-twitter-status-in-tweepy). I want to get the ID of the users that have retweeted a particular tweet.

I tried following the same technique but I'm getting an error. Here's the code:

```
import tweepy

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET)
auth.set_access_token(ACCESS_KEY, ACCESS_SECRET)

api = tweepy.API(auth)

firstTweet = api.user_timeline("github")[0]
print firstTweet.text
print firstTweet.id
results = api.retweeted_by(firstTweet.id) 
print results
```

This returns the 1st tweet and also the tweet ID. It then gives me the following error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "twitter_test.py", line 21, in <module>
    results = api.retweeted_by("357237988863913984") 
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tweepy-2.1-py2.7.egg/tweepy/binder.py", line 197, in _call
    return method.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tweepy-2.1-py2.7.egg/tweepy/binder.py", line 173, in execute
    raise TweepError(error_msg, resp)
tweepy.error.TweepError: [{u'message': u'Sorry, that page does not exist', u'code': 34}]
```

Comment: +1 for the awesome title. (Or should I say *twitle*)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`retweeted_by` is not a part of 1.1 twitter API. Switch to `retweets`:

```
results = api.retweets(firstTweet.id)
```

FYI, quote from [docs](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/statuses/retweeters/ids):

> GET statuses/retweeters/ids
>
> Returns a collection of up to 100 user IDs belonging to users who have
> retweeted the tweet specified by the id parameter.
>
> This method offers similar data to GET statuses/retweets/:id and
> replaces API v1's GET statuses/:id/retweeted_by/ids method.

Comment: Please note the rate limit for this is much lower, only 15, so it might not be the best choice if you are doing a lot of API calls.

Comment: So, which is the best way to do so?